# Hibernate @GeneratedValue doesn't generate autoincremented value as it done before

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i have a course entity based on annotations. when i was creating and saving my courses before, it worked fine, but i changed something and now it shows an error that "NULL not allowed for column "COURSE_ID"; statement:|insert into COURSES (course_id, course_description, course_name, course_links) values (null, ?, ?, ?) "

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSES")
public class Courses {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "course_name", nullable = false)
    private String courseName;

    @Column(name = "course_description")
    private String courseDescription;

    @Column(name = "course_links")
    private String links;

    public void setCourseDescription(String courseDescription) {
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
    }

    public void setLinks(String links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

    public String getCourseDescription() {
        return courseDescription;
    }

    public String getLinks() {
        return links;
    }
    /// constructor
    public Courses(String courseName, String courseDescription, String links) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
        this.links = links;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Courses{" + "id=" + id + ", courseName=" + courseName + ", courseDescription=" + courseDescription + ", links=" + links + '}';
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public Courses(){

    }

}
```

my method for saving courses :

```
SessionFactory sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    public void save(Courses course) {

        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(course);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

i would appreciate any help.

Comment: For some reason, your generated statement is not correct, I think, because the value won't be generated as you pass a NULL value. It shouldn't put any value to the auto-generated field, that is: insert into COURSES (course_description, course_name, course_links) values (?, ?, ?).

Comment: What database do you use? Are you sure that your database supports the generation of ids by identity columns (e.g. oracle doesn't support this type of generation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i recreated a table it doesn't use @generatedvalue. i deleted my table and created it again through h2 console and wrote auto_increment to id field. now it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Missing the strategy part :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "course_id")
private int id;
```